# check if one input is empty (validate a form)

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I have a jQuery code which should look in my form if there is any empty input. If all inputs are empty my code works but when I put in one input a value it doesn't work anymore and it goes through. Could you help me please? Thank you!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#next').click(function() {//My next button
   $('#age, #weight, #target_weight, #size').each(function() {//All field from my form
      if ($(this).val().trim().length == '') {//If all fields are empty -> do...
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('.progressbar-header').offset().top-100}, 250);
        /*Here I want to show the error field on every empty element*/
    $(this).closest('.questions').find('.error').css("visibility","visible");
        $(this).css('border-color', "#ff0000"); 
    
   } else {
      alert("All fields are filled!");
    
    //This will show the next hidden div and hide the last one
    $('.active').removeClass('active').fadeIn().hide()
        .next().show().addClass('active');
    

    return false;
    }
  });
});
});
```

```html
<div class="field personal-informations-icon">
                        <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
                            <span class="title">age</span>
                            <div class="questions">
                                <input style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" id="age" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]" name="age" placeholder="in Jahren" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
                               <div style="visibility: visible;" class="error age_error">This field is required!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
                            <span class="title">weight</span>
                            <div class="questions">
                                <input style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" id="weight" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]" name="weight" placeholder="in KG" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
                               <div style="visibility: visible;" class="error weight_error">This field is required!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
                            <span class="title">target weight</span>
                            <div class="questions">
                                <input id="target_weight" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]*" name="aim-weight" placeholder="in KG" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
                               <div class="error target_weight_error">This field is required!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
                            <span class="title">Body Size</span>
                            <div class="questions">
                                <input id="size" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]*" name="size" placeholder="in cm" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
                               <div class="error size_error">This field is required!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, but the main problem is here:

```
 if ($(this).val().trim().length == '')
```

Length returns a number, and you're attempting to compare it to a string.
I suspect you mean:

```
if ($(this).val().trim() === '')
```

Or

```
if ($(this).val().trim().length === 0)
```

I removed extraneous elements from your code to get at an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Here is a working demo of your MVCE:  [JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69ngn1v1/)

**JQuery**

```
$('#next').click(function() { //My next button
  var isValid = true;
  $('.personal-informations').each(function(i, obj) { //All field from my form
    if ($(this).val().trim() === '') { //If this field is empty -> do...
      /*Here I want to show the error field on every empty element*/
      $(this).css("display", "block");
      $(this).css('border-color', "#ff0000");
      isValid = false;
      console.log(isValid);
    }
  });
  if (isValid) {
    alert("All fields are filled!");
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="field personal-informations-icon">
  <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
    <span class="title">age</span>
    <div class="questions">
      <input id="age" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]" name="age" placeholder="in Jahren" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
      <div class="error age_error">This field is required!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
    <span class="title">weight</span>
    <div class="questions">
      <input id="weight" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]" name="weight" placeholder="in KG" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
      <div class="error weight_error">This field is required!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
    <span class="title">target weight</span>
    <div class="questions">
      <input id="target_weight" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]*" name="aim-weight" placeholder="in KG" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
      <div class="error target_weight_error">This field is required!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="questions-fcm-3 styled-radio">
    <span class="title">Body Size</span>
    <div class="questions">
      <input id="size" class="personal-informations" pattern="[0-9]*" name="size" placeholder="in cm" value="" min="1" aria-required="true" type="number">
      <div class="error size_error">This field is required!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
```

**CSS**

```
.error {
  display: none;
}
```

---

Other comments about your code:

- You have a class assigned to your inputs.  You should use that class
  in your JQuery to bind your event, instead of each input's id.
- You seem to not realize that the each loop is an iteration over the
  inputs.  Inside the each brackets, you are only inspecting one
  particular input.  And it's easiest to refer to that input as
  `$(this)`.  Also, you need to track whether or not you have any empty
  fields.  I've done this using a boolean called `isValid`.  That
  boolean is set to false when an empty field is encountered, and then
  you can check the value of the boolean before displaying the alert.
- If you require numbers only in a field, you should let the user know.
  Either put a label to the side, change your invalid message to state
  that only numbers are allowed, change the input so that anything but
  a number is immediately removed when I type it, or ... something. 
  A user will wonder why you're removing their entry of "11 lbs" and stating that an input is required.
- `console.log()` is your friend.  Use it to debug your own code.